# Specifying Google Credentials When Creating a SubscriberClient using C# Client Library

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-pubsub

I've setup a GCP PubSub processor for our service and it creates a `SubscriberClient` like so

`var subscriptionClient = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(subscriptionName);`.

And I have the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable set and pointing at a valid SA key. Everything works as expected.

However, how can I go about not using/relying on the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable on my local machine?

The Cloud Storage Client libraries allow you to create a storage client like so `StorageClient.Create(GoogleCredentials gcpCredentials);` and I was looking for something like this with the PubSub client libraries but did not find anything. There is `ChannelCredentials` but that does not appear to be for this purpose.

I do see that `SubscriberServiceApiClientBuilder` allows you to specify `JsonCredentials` but I'm not using that client for my use case. As the `SubscriberClient` and `PublisherClient` are more suitable for my purpose given the following from the documentation:

> PublisherClient and SubscriberClient provide simpler APIs for message publishing and subscribing. These classes offer considerably higher performance and simplicity, especially when working with higher message throughput.

Thanks

Comment: A colleague of mine pointed me to
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/PublisherClient.cs#L228

Looks like I could do this in my code and use the result as the ChannelCredentials for ClientCreationSettings to the SubscriberClient.CreateAsync() call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the `ChannelCredentials` manually, in a similar fashion as done in the [`PublisherClient`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/PublisherClient.cs#L228) and passing in `ClientCreationSettings` initialized with credentials set using `GoogleCredentials.ToChannelCredentials()` does the job.

```cs
var subscriptionName = SubscriptionName.FromProjectSubscription("projectId", "subscriptionId");

// create GoogleCredentials
var gcpCredentials = <code that creates valid GoogleCredentials>;

// create ClientCreationSettings with credentials based on the GoogleCredentials created above
var settings = new SubscriberClient.ClientCreationSettings(credentials: gcpCredentials.ToChannelCredentials());

var client = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(<SubscriptionName>, settings);
```

I asked this question in the GitHub `googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client` repo as well. if you want a bit more information about it: [GitHub Issue 1764 Link](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/1764)

Comment: Just in case anyone else had the same problem as me... You need to reference to Grpc.Auth (using Grpc.Auth;) in order to use the extension method ToChannelCredentials()

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMlpG.png

not such method ToChannelCredentials available

Answer (score 1):

Use the SubscriberClientBuilder.
If you create a method that takes in the project id and subscription id for the GCP Pub/Sub you're connecting to, and you feed it a string that has the JSON for the service account creds:

```
public async Task<SubscriberClient> ConnectToGCPPubSub(string projectId, string subscriptionId, string credentialsJson) {
    var subscriberClientBuilder = new SubscriberClientBuilder();
    subscriberClientBuilder.Credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(credentialsJson);
    subscriberClientBuilder.SubscriptionName = new SubscriptionName(projectId, subscriptionId);

    return await subscriberClientBuilder.BuildAsync();
```